# Multiples eventos en metodo on();

Tags: javascript, jquery

buen dia, tengo este fragmento de js en mi sitio

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cart-763').on('load change', function() {
       alert("cambiaste el valor del input");
    }
}
```

cart-763 es un input html de numeros, entonces al cargar la pagina, tengo entendido que con el metodo load deberia ejecutarse las instrucciones del alert, pero no se ejecuta al momento de la carga, pero si se ejecuta si modifico el valor del input.

estuve leyendo y al parecer si se podia agregar multiples eventos como on change click etc, en el metodo on(), pero no me funciona, o estoy realizandolo mal?
psdta: el evento change si es necesario, pero tambien necesito que se ejecute al momento de la carga de la pagina.

ya voy 1 dia entero con esto.

Comment: _Para capturar eventos "load" en la ventana, ese evento de carga debe ser enviado directamente a la ventana._ Esto según [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event). En pocas palabras: ese evento debés asignarlo a _window_, no al input que mencionás.

Comment: Acá un poco la solución a multiples eventos en ingles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/how-can-i-trigger-the-same-function-from-multiple-events-with-jquery

Answer (score 2):

El evento de carga no vas a poder registrarlo porque ya ocurrió. Analicemos línea a línea:

```javascript
// Esto se ejecuta cuando el documento está cargado y listo
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    // La siguiente línea requiere que un elemento con id "cart-763" exista
    // por tanto el evento "load" ya ocurrió
    $('#cart-763').on('load change', function() {
       alert("cambiaste el valor del input");
    }
}
```

Por tanto, tu única opción es ejecutar el evento al terminar de cargar el documento:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
    function manejaEvento() {
       alert("cambiaste el valor del input");
    }

    $('#cart-763').on('change', manejaEvento);

    manejaEvento(); // on load
}
```