# Acceder al control de un botón con jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

¿Cómo puedo acceder al control de un botón que es llamado por `jQuery` y añadido al DOM con `$("#tag").load()`?.

El botón carga bien en el DOM, les adjunto mi código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#Actualiza").click(function(){
               $("#Empleados").load("TablaEmpleados.php");
        });


  $("#boto").click(function() {
    $("#Marcajes").load("TablaMarca.php");
    alert($(this).text())
    //document.getElementById("Marcajes").innerHTML = element;//Asignar valor 
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="boto" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Boto</button>
</div>
```

El botón "boto" se crea bien, pero después al cargarse en el DOM, no puedo acceder a él.

Comment: He replicado el código que nos muestras y funciona correctamente, revisa la consola del navegador si hay errores o verifica que el CDN o los paquetes de JQuery en tu proyecto funcionen correctamente.

Comment: Hola. El elemento #boto, no lo tengo cargado en el DOM original , viene de la carga "load() de la parte del php Tablaempleados.php.

Comment: Hola. El elemento boto, no lo tengo cargado en el DOM original , viene de la carga load de la parte del php Tablaempleados.php. Cuando realizo la activacion el boto aparece pero al realizar click,  no realiza el proceso de load TablaMarca.php.

Comment: Intenta utilizar **On**, probablemente sea por la delegación de eventos, ya que al asignarlo aun no existe dicho elemento.

Comment: Revisa esta pregunta, puede ayudarte [Evento on](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/587768/multiples-eventos-en-metodo-on)

Comment: He revisado el código y sigo sin saber el porque pasa, Me comentan Utilizar On ??Que es un evento? onClick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando se añaden elementos nuevos al DOM de forma dinámica, éstos no tienen eventos asociados.
Para ello es necesario usar la delegación.

Prueba cambiando

```
$("#boto").click(function() {
```

por

```
$("body").click("#boto", function() {
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola. No me funciona, al cargar todo el DOM, me realiza los dos eventos #Actualiza + #boto. Solamente que haga Click en el boton Actualiza, me hace los dos eventos..Yo quiero 1º que al cliCar en #Actualiza , me cargue la parte del php , que dentro habra un boton denominado id=boto. y cuando me carge esa parte al realizar click en el boto , me carge otra parte de codigo php.

Comment: En ese caso debes repasar como funciona la propagación de eventos y revisar cómo se están propagando en tu código.

Podrías probar con:

`$("body").click("#boto", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();`